# IntelliJ don't recognise implicit imports as usefull

Tags: json, scala, intellij-idea, spray

I use spray json in my application and for models I need to write `JsonProtocol` companions.

Because in the service I have more models, I have two options to use these `JsonProtocols`:

**a)** make `TableauErrorResponseJsonProtocol` a `trait` and extend it by my service

**b)** make `TableauErrorResponseJsonProtocol` an `object` and import it where I need in my service (as in picture)

I try to avoid using option `a)` because I already have some extends for my service, so I don't want to use `with x, with y, with z,` ....

But, for option `b)`, when I want to rearrange the code (`CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + L`), **IntelliJ will remove all these imports**, because are "unused". In reallity, these both are used by the next line (`response.data.parseJson.convertTo[MyClass]`).

How I can avoid it? thanks

[image: Unused imports]

Comment: `Alt + Enter` on the import . And you will see an option like `Mark import as always used in this project`

Comment: ah, so easy. Everyday you can learn something :)) Can you make your comment as answer to mark it as solution? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Alt + Enter` on the import . And you will see an option like `Mark import as always used in this project`